# Need to concatenate multiple arrays that are withing a singular array and set first value of each array as key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => first_name [1] => first_name ) [1] => Array ( [0] => last_name [1] => last_name ) [2] => Array ( [0] => company_id [1] => company_id ) [3] => Array ( [0] => position [1] => position ) [4] => Array ( [0] => phone [1] => phone ) [5] => Array ( [0] => email [1] => email ) [6] => Array ( [0] => source_id [1] => source_id ) )
```

There are multiple arrays withing a single array. I need to concatenate these arrays into one array and set the first value, of each array, as key. How would I go about doing that in JavaScript, AJAX, or Jquery.

I need it something like this; first_name=>first_name, last_name=>last_name, etc.

Comment: Have fun doing that with AJAX

Comment: I'm new to all 3. I had a feeling AJAX didn't fit, but I left it in just in case.

Comment: what do you mean by `concatenate these arrays into one array  and set ... as key`?

Comment: @Pengyy In the example there are multiple arrays inside a singular array. I want them all as a singular array. The first value of each array should be key for the respective value. ie; first_name=>first_name, last_name=>last_name etc., all in a singular array instead of multiple arrays.

Comment: Can you give an example of your array?

Comment: @Tai Le The array in the question is the actual array. The values and key will change based on user input. I want it to look as follows; first_name=>first_name, last_name=>last_name, etc. The first value of every array should be the key for the second value, all within a singular array instead of multiple arrays.

Comment: *"The array in the question is the actual array."* - Except that that isn't JS syntax and it's hard to read. It would've been better to show it as an array literal as in the accepted answer.

Comment: I'll remember that if it comes up again. My background is PHP and that is a literal PHP array. The array is sent to a PHP file via Jquery and echoed back. I figured it would be evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript cannot have non-numeric keys, so I have assumed that you'd actually like the output to be an object.

```
var data = [
  ['first_name', 'John'],
  ['last_name', 'Smith'],
  ['position', 'Boss'],
  ['email', 'john@smith.com'],
  ['phone', '0432 987 654'],
];

var parsed = data.reduce(function (parsed, item) {
  parsed[item[0]] = item[1];
  return parsed;
}, {});
```

With working JSBin fiddle - https://jsbin.com/mobiwaduki/edit?js,console